# Relationship between eigenvalues of summation of two matrices one is diagonal

Tags: eigenvalues, tridiagonal-matrices

I wonder if someone can prove/disprove the following inequality,

$\lambda_i(A+mI) \leq \lambda_i(A+K) \leq \lambda_i(A+MI)$

where $A$ is a real symmetric Metzler matrix with real and nonpositive eigenvalues and $K$ is a diagonal matrix. $M$ and $m$ are the greatest and the least elements of $K$ respectively.

I have seen that the above inequality holds for all examples I tried but I would like to prove it mathematically or find a counterexample.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $\lambda_i(A+xI)=\lambda_i(A)+x$?

Comment: Yes, for sure !

Comment: But how does that help?

Comment: It shows that you can add any real multiple of $I$ to $A$ or $K$ (and change $m$ and $M$ accordingly) in the question, and what you get is equivalent to the original claim. So, the assumption about the eigenvalues of $A$ is irrelevant. It also suffices to prove the inequality $\lambda_i(A)\le \lambda_i(A+K)$ whenever $K$ is a real diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries; the second one then follows since $A+MI=(A+K)+(MI-K)$.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the Interlacing Eigenvalue Theorem (Golub and Van Loan "Matrix Computations", 4th edition, Theorem 8.1.8), and holds for any real symmetric n by n $A$, whether or not Metzler or having nonpositive eigenvalues.

$A + K = A + mI +$ sum of n nonnegative multiples of rank one matrices of the form $cc^T$ for $||c||_2 = 1$.  The ith rank one matrix can be taken as $e_ie_i^T$, where $e_i$ is the ith unit vector, with multiple $(K_{ii}-m)$. Interlacing holds as each successive nonnegative multiple of rank one matrix is added, and therefore for $A + mI$ vs. $A + K$.  Similarly for $A + K$ vs. $A + MI$.